# Error occurs when Trying to install the MLNX_OFED driver

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to install the MLNX_OFED driver.
version: MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0

on linux ubuntu 21.04 kernel version 5.11.0-20

when I run the command "./mlnxofedinstall --with-nvmf --with-nfsrdma --enable-gds --add-kernel-support"
This is the output I get:

```
See log file /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.11.0-25-generic/mlnx_iso.7901_logs/mlnx_ofed_iso.7901.log

Checking if all needed packages are installed...
Building MLNX_OFED_LINUX DEBS . Please wait...
Creating metadata-rpms for 5.11.0-25-generic ...
WARNING: If you are going to configure this package as a repository, then please note
WARNING: that it is not signed, therefore, you need to set 'trusted=yes' in the sources.list file.
WARNING: Example: deb [trusted=yes] file:/<path to MLNX_OFED DEBS folder> ./
Created /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.11.0-25-generic/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-ubuntu21.04-ext.tgz
Removing old packages...
Installing /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.11.0-25-generic/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-ubuntu21.04-ext
/tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-5.11.0-25-generic/MLNX_OFED_LINUX-5.4-1.0.3.0-ubuntu21.04-ext/mlnxofedinstall --force --without-dkms --with-nvmf --with-nfsrdma --enable-gds
Logs dir: /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX.355349.logs
General log file: /tmp/MLNX_OFED_LINUX.355349.logs/general.log

Below is the list of MLNX_OFED_LINUX packages that you have chosen
(some may have been added by the installer due to package dependencies):

ofed-scripts
mlnx-tools
mlnx-ofed-kernel-utils
mlnx-ofed-kernel-modules
iser-modules
isert-modules
srp-modules
mlnx-nfsrdma-modules
mlnx-nvme-modules
rdma-core
libibverbs1
ibverbs-utils
ibverbs-providers
libibverbs-dev
libibverbs1-dbg
libibumad3
libibumad-dev
ibacm
librdmacm1
rdmacm-utils
librdmacm-dev
mstflint
ibdump
libibmad5
libibmad-dev
libopensm
opensm
opensm-doc
libopensm-devel
libibnetdisc5
infiniband-diags
mft
kernel-mft-modules
perftest
ibutils2
ar-mgr
dump-pr
ibsim
ibsim-doc
ucx
sharp
hcoll
openmpi
mpitests
knem-modules
libdapl2
dapl2-utils
libdapl-dev
dpcp
srptools
mlnx-ethtool
mlnx-iproute2
rshim

This program will install the MLNX_OFED_LINUX package on your machine.
Note that all other Mellanox, OEM, OFED, RDMA or Distribution IB packages will be removed.
Those packages are removed due to conflicts with MLNX_OFED_LINUX, do not reinstall them.

Checking SW Requirements...
One or more required packages for installing MLNX_OFED_LINUX are missing.
Attempting to install the following missing packages:
libnl-3-dev libnl-route-3-dev flex tk gfortran libgfortran4 bison
Removing old packages...
Installing new packages
Installing ofed-scripts-5.4...
Installing mlnx-tools-5.2.0...
Installing mlnx-ofed-kernel-utils-5.4...
Installing mlnx-ofed-kernel-modules-5.4...
Installing iser-modules-5.4...
Installing isert-modules-5.4...
Installing srp-modules-5.4...
Installing mlnx-nfsrdma-modules-5.4...
Installing mlnx-nvme-modules-5.4...
Installing rdma-core-54mlnx1...
Installing libibverbs1-54mlnx1...
Installing ibverbs-utils-54mlnx1...
Installing ibverbs-providers-54mlnx1...
Installing libibverbs-dev-54mlnx1...
Installing libibverbs1-dbg-54mlnx1...
Installing libibumad3-54mlnx1...
Installing libibumad-dev-54mlnx1...
Installing ibacm-54mlnx1...
Installing librdmacm1-54mlnx1...
Installing rdmacm-utils-54mlnx1...
Installing librdmacm-dev-54mlnx1...
Installing mstflint-4.16.0...
Installing ibdump-6.0.0...
Installing libibmad5-54mlnx1...
Installing libibmad-dev-54mlnx1...
Installing libopensm-5.9.0.MLNX20210617.c9f2ade...
Installing opensm-5.9.0.MLNX20210617.c9f2ade...
Installing opensm-doc-5.9.0.MLNX20210617.c9f2ade...
Installing libopensm-devel-5.9.0.MLNX20210617.c9f2ade...
Installing libibnetdisc5-54mlnx1...
Installing infiniband-diags-54mlnx1...
Installing mft-4.17.0...
Installing kernel-mft-modules-4.17.0...
Installing perftest-4.5...
Installing ibutils2-2.1.1...
Installing ar-mgr-1.0...
Installing dump-pr-1.0...
Installing ibsim-0.10...
Installing ibsim-doc-0.10...
Installing ucx-1.11.0...
Installing sharp-2.5.0.MLNX20210613.83fe753...
Installing hcoll-4.7.3199...
Installing openmpi-4.1.2a1...
Installing mpitests-3.2.20...
Installing knem-modules-1.1.4.90mlnx1...
Installing libdapl2-2.1.10.1.mlnx...
Installing dapl2-utils-2.1.10.1.mlnx...
Installing libdapl-dev-2.1.10.1.mlnx...
Installing dpcp-1.1.12...
Installing srptools-54mlnx1...
Installing mlnx-ethtool-5.10...
Installing mlnx-iproute2-5.11.0...
Installing rshim-2.0.6...
Selecting previously unselected package mlnx-fw-updater.
(Reading database ... 203000 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mlnx-fw-updater_5.4-1.0.3.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mlnx-fw-updater (5.4-1.0.3.0) ...
Setting up mlnx-fw-updater (5.4-1.0.3.0) ...

Added 'RUN_FW_UPDATER_ONBOOT=no to /etc/infiniband/openib.conf

Initializing...
Attempting to perform Firmware update...
No devices found!

Installation passed successfully
To load the new driver, run:
/etc/init.d/openibd restart
Note: In order to load the new nvme-rdma and nvmet-rdma modules, the nvme module must be reloaded.
```

and when I run the "/etc/init.d/openibd restart" command to restart the driver I get the following failings:

```
Unloading HCA driver:                                      [  OK  ]
Loading Mellanox MLX5_IB HCA driver:                       [FAILED]
Loading Mellanox MLX5 HCA driver:                          [FAILED]
Loading HCA driver and Access Layer:                       [FAILED]

Please run /usr/sbin/sysinfo-snapshot.py to collect the debug information
and open an issue in the http://support.mellanox.com/SupportWeb/service_center/SelfService
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say there is a kernel mismatch between what the package supplies and your running kernel, 5.4-1.0.3.0 -> 5.11.0-20. That is quite a big gap. Either find a newer version, or you may have to find the modules source, hack it for the later kernel and rebuild. dmesg should give you at least some info on what is going wrong.

Comment: You'll be better served at serverfault.com

Comment: @Bib 5.4-1.0.3.0 is the MLNX OFED release version. This version supports 5.11.0; as stated here: https://docs.mellanox.com/display/MLNXOFEDv541030/General+Support
For the OP: please provide additional logs: dmesg, lsmod | grep -i mlnx, /var/log/messages.